# Aggregating data in a WSO2 DAS Gadget

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-esb

I've built a proxy server in ESB which will search a item in 3 other systems and now I'd like to show some data on dashboards like:

- Bar graph showing average request time per system.
- Percentage of calls that are being served by each system.

Every sample I find just receives some data from ESB and show on DAS so I don't know how to work on this data.

Comment: You need to create a proxy per backend system and configure WSO2 ESB to send statistic data to DAS, follow this link http://nadeeshaan.blogspot.com/2016/02/working-with-wso2-esb-event-sink-and.html

Comment: What is the DAS version you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest one (3.0.1)